# remove few lines from the pdf version on the first page of my thesis but still there

Tags: thesis

In my thesis, in overleaf, I use my university thesis as document class.
In the fisrt page there are command for head of school and nominating professor which I want to remove them. But when I deactive the command by % and recompile the document they are not removed still there with other words in pdf version. Just wondering if you could let me know how can I remove them?
for example:

```
\headSchool{Prof. Mike Niki} % vice provost name 
\nomProf{Dr Adam Woods}
```

I tried this (even I removed them)

```
% \headSchool{Prof. Mike Niki} % vice provost name 
% \nomProf{Dr Adam Woods}
```

When I compile, in the PDF version this can be seen:

Head of School: Prof. Thom Jackson
Nominating Professor: My Nominating Professor

Comment: Welcome to TeX - LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.``

Comment: what is your university thesis documentclass?

Comment: It seems to me your university has gone to some length to prevent you from doing what you want to do.  You can still do it my editing the document class, but I would not recommend it.

Comment: If you could just add the name of the documentclass, this would help for future reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of commenting the lines, try

```
\headSchool{ }
\nomProf{ }
```

that is, with an empty space between the brackets.
It's likely that *Thom Jackson* and *My Nominating Professor* are the default values of the commands.

Comment: Thanks Alessandro, I followed your advise but the title are still there

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try deleting all of the auxiliary files (e.g. ending in log, aux, dvi, lof, lot, bit, idx, glo, bbl, ilg, toc, ind, out, blg, which is pretty much everything that doesn't end in tex, albeit with a few exceptions), and then recompiling. Most IDE's (such as TexStudio have a button for this in their Tools tab).

Comment: Thanks so much Oliver,

Comment: @MohammadAliEkhtiari If it worked then please consider upvoting/accepting, and if not then please specify what's not working.